# XSD Display empty elements for null data

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, jaxb

I'm working on soap webservices. i want to know how to display response xml with empty elements when the data is null.

Eg:

**My XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="TrackInfo">
  <xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:string"  />
  <xs:element name="AverageSpeed" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

**Sample XML document:**

```
<TrackInfo>
<Name>Barcelona</Name>
<Length>4591</Length>
<AverageSpeed>20</AverageSpeed>
</TrackInfo>
```

**Java Code to set values**

```
TrackInfo trackinfo= new TrackInfo();
trackinfo.setName("Barcelona");
trackinfo.setLength("4591");
trackinfo.setAverageSpeed("20");
```

There are cases where i may not have data to set and in that case i want to display xml with empty elements. Otherwise i need to handle null cases for huge code.

```
TrackInfo trackinfo= new TrackInfo();
trackinfo.setName(null);
trackinfo.setLength(null);
trackinfo.setAverageSpeed(null);

<TrackInfo>
<Name></Name>
<Length></Length>
<AverageSpeed></AverageSpeed>
</TrackInfo>
```

if i try with nillable=true i get response as

```
<TrackInfo>
<Name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<Length xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  instance"/>
<AverageSpeed xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</TrackInfo>
```

Please advise how to proceed for any other possibilities

Thanks.

Comment: `i want to know how to display response xml with empty elements when the data is null` ... it appears that using `nillable="true"` is achieving this.  Then what else is the problem?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the below

```
TrackInfo trackinfo= new TrackInfo();
trackinfo.setName("");
trackinfo.setLength("");
trackinfo.setAverageSpeed("");
```

The response would have empty tags.

Comment: Yes. i do the same, but i have a huge xml and i need to check for the NULL values (if null condition)for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `default = ""` to your `<xs:element>` tags.  Try using this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="TrackInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" default = "" />
                <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:string" default = "" />
                <xs:element name="AverageSpeed" type="xs:string" default = "" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: if i try with nillable=true i get something like  <Name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>  . Please check my above question, have updated the response for nillable=true

Comment: Yes but if you try to access the value of a nillable empty tag, do you get `null` in your Java code?  From what I can tell, you will always get `<tag/>` for an empty tag rather than `<tag></tag>`.

Comment: But response xml perspective i want to display empty tags and not   <Name xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

Comment: How are you rendering the tags?  Is there an option to remove all attributes?

Comment: I'm doing TrackInfo trackinfo= new TrackInfo();
trackinfo.setName("");
trackinfo.setLength("");
trackinfo.setAverageSpeed("");  to make it empty tags

Comment: Try using `default="true"` in your element tags.